# Inspec test multiple entities

Tags: chef-infra, inspec

I am writing inspec tests for my chef recipes where there are 5 files which needs to tested for their mode. All of them should have the same mode 0755.

```
describe file('/dev') do
 its('mode') { should cmp '00755' }
end
```

This is the sytax I am using. But this tests only 1 file(/dev). Is is possible to test multiple files using a single test block?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you can use ruby code to test multiple entities

```
dirs = ["/lib","/bin","/dev"]
dirs.each do |path|
    describe file(path) do
        its('type') { should eq :directory }
        it { should be_directory }
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't exactly 'single test block', but you could iterate over file list:

```
%w(/dev /tmp).each do |path|
  describe file(path)
    its(:mode) { should cmp '00755' }
  end
end
```